# DB queries with "In" seem to be sorted

Tags: sql, sqlite

There are clients(companies) and contacts in two tables. Both contacts and clients have their own fields. But they all have an id that is a primaryKey. In addition, there are "links" between clients and contacts - each client can be assigned a contact and vice versa. There is a third table for this, called 'assignment', which has only two fields - company id and contact id.

Suppose we have linked a contact with id 3 to a company with id 12076. Next, we have linked a contact with id 10, and the last contact with id 5. Сheck our result:

```
SELECT contactId FROM assignment WHERE companyId = 12076;
```

The result is correct -

[image]

After these steps, at some point I need to get the FIELDS of contacts associated with the company I need. There is a company 12076, I need to get all the contact fields associated with it. I made a request like this:

```
SELECT id, fullName FROM contacts WHERE contacts.rowid IN (SELECT contactId FROM assignment WHERE companyId = 12076);
```

This request displays the contacts I need and their fields. Exactly 3 contacts, but there is one problem - they are displayed in sorted order, sorted by id.
[image]

I need the contact fields to be displayed in the order in which they were added. How can i dow this? Maybe i need to use JOIN?

Comment: There is no "order in which they were added" for the contacts in your original table unless there be one or more columns which maintains that ordering.  So, add a column for the order, and then use `ORDER BY some_col` to get the order you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I guess I just don't understand the "IN" logic. It is clear that I don’t need sorting as such, they are already stored in the database in the right order. It's just that in the case of requesting fields with "IN" (see the second request), they are displayed in ascending order, which I do not need.

Comment: `they are already stored in the database in the right order` ... there is NO order inside the database.  You need a column which maintains the ordering, period.

Comment: From https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#the_order_by_clause: *If a SELECT statement that returns more than one row does not have an ORDER BY clause, the order in which the rows are returned is undefined.* This means that the order of the rows of `SELECT contactId FROM assignment WHERE companyId = 12076;` is **undefined**. So what you are looking for can't be done. Even if somehow you get correct results there is no guarantee that it will always work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default an SQLite table has a Rowid column. We can use this column in ORDER BY.
If we want the ContactId's in the order they were inserted into the table contacts we can join onto contacts and order by it's Rowid.
See [https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-autoincrement/][1]

> ```
> create table companies(id int);
> create table contacts (id int);
> create table assignment(companyId int,contactId int);
> insert into companies values(12076);
> insert into contacts values(10),(3),(5);
> insert into assignment values (12076,3),(12076,10),(12076,5);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT a.contactId 
> FROM assignment a
> JOIN contacts c
> on a.contactId = c.id
> WHERE companyId = 12076
> order by c.Rowid;
> ```

> ```
> | contactId |
> | --------: |
> |        10 |
> |         3 |
> |         5 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=37450c957a4a3974e82caa1259064f69)*

Comment: Thanks dude. If you make a request, which is indicated in your answer, then the result will be the same with "order by Rowid" and without it. The sequence 3, 10, 5 will be displayed. I need to display the contact fields stored in the contacts table in the same sequence, knowing only the companyId.

Comment: I've modified my answer